# Create POST Request in air /as3 for youtube direct upload

Tags: actionscript-3, post, air, youtube-api

I'm developing a simple youtube app in adobe air, so far I could get the approval window in youtube and getting the token for uploading. However I'm stuck in the part where you send the data on POST with all the information (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading)

I already loaded my video data as a bytearray, what I need is to create the whole POST request containing all the information as it shows in the link. (the xml atom feed, the bytearray data, etc.) I have all the information needed, I just need to structure the POST request.

How to do that in as3/air? Do I create all the information as URLVariables? which ones are headers and which ones arent? How do you add the --< boundary_string> to the POST? How do you add the bytearra to the POST? All help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I've always found the built-in classes URLLoader, URLRequest etc. to be somewhat lacking with regard to the kinds of details you're talking about you may want to look into using a third-party library like "as3httpclient" or perhaps an even more abstracted thing like this: http://code.google.com/p/air-youtube-uploader/

Answer (score 0):

I have always done something like this when sending POST variables:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="loginServ" resultFormat="text" result="onResult(event)" method="POST" url="http://www.myurl.com/login.php"/>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Then you would have two functions, one for sending the request and one for handling the result you get back:

```
private function login():void{
    //Make a new Object to hold all of your POST variables
    var reqInfo:Object = new Object();

    //Then set the properties of that Object to be each POST variable
    reqInfo.username = "admin";
    reqInfo.password = "password";

    //Finally, send the request with the Object as the parameter
    loginServ.send(reqInfo);
}

private function onResult(e:ResultEvent):void {
    trace("Result:" + e.result);
}
```